# Cannot access EditText data from AlertDialog in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-edittext, fragment, android-alertdialog

I am looking to create an AlertDialog with two EditTexts. The AlertDialog exists inside of a fragment.

In the `onCreateView` I am getting a reference both to the layout of the Fragment as well as the Layout I am using for I am using for the AlertDialog.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.daily_tasks, container, false);
    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.daily_dialog, container, false);

    floatDailyButton = (FloatingActionButton) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.floatDailyButton);
    taskTitle = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.taskTitleEditText);
    taskDescription = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.taskDescriptionEditText);

    floatDailyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("Tapped", "tapped");
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setView(R.layout.daily_dialog);
            builder.setPositiveButton("Save Tasks", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    if (getText() == true) {
                        saveData();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Set a title", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
            builder.show();
        }
    });
    return view;
```

When the user presses the 'positive' button in the Dialog, I want to extract the content from the EditTexts:

```
public boolean getText() {
    try {
        titleText = taskTitle.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), titleText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i("title text", titleText);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    try {
        descriptionText = taskDescription.getText().toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

However no matter what value is in these EditTexts, when I hit the positive button, the AlertDialog closes and the value in the EditTexts is null.

What is wrong here?

Comment: Change `builder.setView(R.layout.daily_dialog);` to `builder.setView(dialogView);`, and you'll have to make `dialogView` `final` with your current code. When you pass a layout resource to the `setView()` call, it will inflate it itself, so the layout shown in the `Dialog` ends up being a different instance than the one you inflated and found your `View`s in.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks! I thought that I was somehow losing the reference I created with the dialogView object, and I understand now how that was happening.